# Ionic Deploy Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have been using Ionic Deploy for some time now to update code but out of nowhere this week it has stopped working completely. I have tried creating a new app and it was the same result. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: Sorry I had to reinstall my emulator. I debugged and I don't get any errors.

Comment: My deploys on my account are going up though.